# Imprimir en pantalla los atributos de un objeto en C#

Tags: c#, objeto, clase, c#-8.0

Tengo una clase llamada Empleado en la cual imprimo los atributos de un empleado.
Pero en el caso de que tenga un empleado numero dos existe alguna forma en la cual podria imprimir los atributos de todos los empleados sin tener que ir uno por uno haciendo lo mimsmo que hice para el empleado uno.

El siguiente es mi codigo el cual esta separado en dos:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Dominio
{
    public class Empleado
    {
        public string Nombre {get; set;}

        public string Apellido { get; set;}

        public DateTime FechaNacimiento { get; set;}

        public decimal ValorHora { get; set;}

        public int Antiguedad { get; set;}

        public int HorasTrabajadas { get; set;}


        public Empleado(string nombre, string apellido, DateTime fechaNacimiento, decimal valorHora, int antiguedad, int horasTrabajadas)
        {
            Nombre = nombre;
            Apellido = apellido;
            FechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
            ValorHora = valorHora;
            Antiguedad = antiguedad;
            HorasTrabajadas = horasTrabajadas;
        }
   }
}
```

```
using Dominio;

namespace PracticoDos
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

                Empleado empleadoUno = new Empleado("Henran", "Vetrale", new DateTime(2015, 12, 25), 20, 4, 30);
                foreach (var prop in empleadoUno.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(empleadoUno, null));
                }
                
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te propongo que sobrescribas el **método ToString**. Este **método ToString** está definido en la **clase Object**, de la cual descienden todos los tipos de datos en **C#**, por lo que en tu clase vamos a definir una nueva versión de este método.

Tu código quedaría así:

```
public class Empleado
{
    public string Nombre {get; set;}
    public string Apellido { get; set;}
    public DateTime FechaNacimiento { get; set;}
    public decimal ValorHora { get; set;}
    public int Antiguedad { get; set;}
    public int HorasTrabajadas { get; set;}

    public Empleado(string nombre, string apellido, DateTime fechaNacimiento, decimal valorHora, int antiguedad, int horasTrabajadas)
    {
        Nombre = nombre;
        Apellido = apellido;
        FechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
        ValorHora = valorHora;
        Antiguedad = antiguedad;
        HorasTrabajadas = horasTrabajadas;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Nombre: {0}", Nombre));
        sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Apellido: {0}", Apellido));
        sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Fecha de nacimiento: {0}", FechaNacimiento));
        sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Hora: {0}", ValorHora));
        sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Antiguedad: {0}", Antiguedad));
        sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Horas trabajadas: {0}", HorasTrabajadas));

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Aquí se sobrescribe el **método ToString** de la **clase Empleado**, para ello se hace uso de la **palabra clave override**. Dentro de este método se declara la **variable sb** de tipo **StringBuilder** la cual será la encargada de crearnos el texto para cada propiedad del objeto y su respectivo valor. Finalmente se retorna el texto deseado.

Posteriormente podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
foreach (var e in listaEmpleados)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
```

Recorres tu lista de empleados y por cada empleado invocas el **método ToString**.

En caso de tener empleados que no están guardados en una lista, es igual de fácil:

```
Empleado empleadoUno = new Empleado("Henran", "Vetrale", new DateTime(2015, 12, 25), 20, 4, 30);
empleadoUno.ToString();

Empleado empleadoDos = new Empleado("Juan", "Perez", new DateTime(2017, 12, 25), 20, 4, 30);
empleadoDos.ToString();
```

**Nota**: Para hacer uso de la **clase StringBuilder** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Text;
```

**Actualización**:

En vez de usar el **método AppendLine** al sobrescribir el **método ToString**, podrías usar el **método AppendFormat** de la **clase StringBuilder**, de esta forma la cadena a imprimir quedará formateada, y ya no hará falta hacer uso de la **sintaxis string.Format**.

Tu código podría quedar ahora como:

```
sb.AppendFormat("Nombre: {0}\n", Nombre);
```

Ahora podrás usar este **método AppendFormat** por cada propiedad que desees imprimir, **\n** es para hacer un **salto de línea**, es decir como si apretaras la **tecla Enter** a la hora de imprimir cada propiedad.

Comment: Mejor aún, usa [`AppendFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.appendformat#system-text-stringbuilder-appendformat(system-string-system-object())). https://stackoverflow.com/a/349736/13419694

Comment: @Mateo gracias, ya incluí esa variante en mi respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Quizas podrías utilizar una lista de empleados estatica creada en la clase. Los vas añadiendo y despues los recorres con dos foreachs.

```
 public class Empleado
 {   
     public string Nombre { get; set; }
     public string Apellido { get; set; }
     public DateTime FechaNacimiento { get; set; }
     public decimal ValorHora { get; set; }
     public int Antiguedad { get; set; }
     public int HorasTrabajadas { get; set; }
     public Empleado(string nombre, string apellido, DateTime fechaNacimiento, decimal valorHora, int antiguedad, int horasTrabajadas)
     {
         Nombre = nombre;
         Apellido = apellido;
         FechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
         ValorHora = valorHora;
         Antiguedad = antiguedad;
         HorasTrabajadas = horasTrabajadas;

         // Aquí añadimos el empleado a la lista.
         Empleados.Add(this); 
     }

     // Creamos la lista estatica
     public static List<Empleado> Empleados  = new List<Empleado>(); 

 }
```

Creamos los empleados y los recorremos con foreach

```
Empleado empleadoUno = new Empleado("Henran", "Vetrale", new DateTime(2015, 12, 25), 20, 4, 30);
Empleado empleadoDos = new Empleado("Alfredo", "Veltran", new DateTime(2015, 9, 4), 420, 6, 30);
Empleado empleadoTres = new Empleado("Mercedes", "Pacheco", new DateTime(2012, 4, 7), 220, 1, 10);

foreach (Empleado empleado in Empleado.Empleados )
{
    foreach (var prop in empleado.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(empleado, null));
    }
}
```